# Components that DatePicker is composed from

Tags: android, android-datepicker

What's the name of the components that DatePicker and TimePicker are composed from? (a field with arrows that change its value - have a look at the picture below). Is something like this already accessible (I cannot find it in the list of components in the GUI designer), or do I have to create my own version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to create your own version.. 
There is [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) but is only available from API version 11 but I don't know how you could add the months there in format MMM...

You can simply do a custom component composed of a edit text and two buttons, a button on top and one at the bottom of the edit text.. also I think you can find the + and - buttons under android resources from your android SDK installation.

I hope it helps.